# How to make an OUTER JOIN return ZERO instead of NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, outer-join

I am trying to accomplish this on SQL Server. The simplest table structure with data is shown below.

```
Table:Blog

BlogID, Title
----------------
1, FirstBlog
23, Pizza

Table:User

UserID, Name
-------------------
123, james
444, John


Table:UserBlogMapping

UserBlogMappingID, BlogID,UserID
----------------------------------
1, 1, 123
```

I want to get FormID and UserBlogMappingID in one SQL query. If provided UserID is not in the mapping table, return ZERO otherwise return the valid userBlogMappingID. I am trying to run the below query but its not correct.

```
SELECT 
    B.BlogID, 
    BUM.BlogUserMappingID 
FROM 
    Blog AS B
        LEFT JOIN BlogUserMapping AS BUM ON B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID
WHERE 
    (B.BlogID = 23)  -- it exists in the table
    AND BUM.userID = 444 -- it is NOT in the mmaping table but i want a ZERO return in such case
```

**Assumption:**
We can assume that the UserID provided in the WHERE clause is always  valid UserID and is present in the User table.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the criteria for the userID=444 in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN.

And an ISNULL or a COALESCE to change a NULL to a 0.

Example using table variables:

```
declare @Blog table (BlogID int, Title varchar(30));
insert into @Blog (BlogId, Title) values
(1, 'FirstBlog'),
(23, 'Pizza');

declare @User table (UserID int, Name varchar(30));
insert into @User (UserID, Name) values
(123,'james'),
(444,'John');


declare @BlogUserMapping table (BlogUserMappingID int, BlogID int, UserID int);
insert into @BlogUserMapping (BlogUserMappingID, BlogID, UserID) values
(1, 1, 123),
(2, 23, 123),
(3, 1, 444);


-- Using the criteria in ON clause of the LEFT JOIN 
SELECT 
 B.BlogID, 
 ISNULL(BUM.BlogUserMappingID,0) as BlogUserMappingID
FROM @Blog B 
LEFT JOIN @BlogUserMapping BUM ON (B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID AND BUM.userID = 444)
WHERE B.BlogID = 23;

-- If there are more BlogId=23 with userID=444.
-- But only 1 row needs to be returned then you could also GROUP BY and take the maximum BlogUserMappingID
SELECT 
 B.BlogID, 
 MAX(ISNULL(BUM.BlogUserMappingID,0)) as BlogUserMappingID
FROM @Blog B 
LEFT JOIN @BlogUserMapping BUM ON (B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID AND BUM.userID = 444)
WHERE B.BlogID = 23
GROUP BY B.BlogID;

-- Using an OR in the WHERE clause would also return a 0. 
-- But it would also return nothing if the mapping table has a BlogID=23 with a userID<>444.
-- So not usefull in this case.
SELECT 
 B.BlogID, 
 ISNULL(BUM.BlogUserMappingID,0) as BlogUserMappingID
FROM @Blog B 
LEFT JOIN @BlogUserMapping BUM ON B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID
WHERE B.BlogID = 23
  AND (BUM.userID IS NULL OR BUM.userID = 444);
```

Comment: are you sure that we will keep "BUM.userID = 444" at the end and not in the LEFT JOIN clause?

Comment: @LukStorms No, it doesn't do the same thing. It's not an alternative way of achieving the same results. Think about what happens when the `LEFT JOIN` matches, but it only matches with rows where `BUM.userID <> 444`.

Comment: @hvd Ok, I've changed it.  Should have tested with a 23 in the mapping table before posting. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @LukStorms even if i correct the above query with your suggestion, it is returning more than one rows if there are more than one records in the 'BlogUserMapping' table against a certain 'BlogID' (not just the one with matching 'BUM.UserID'). For NO matching 'BUM.UserID', it works fine.

Comment: @user1451111 Ok, added an extra query that uses a group by.  I thought you wanted all the BlogUserMapping with a certain BlogID and UserID.